# How can I return this object read in from a file?

Tags: java, object, input, io, return-type

So what I am trying to do here is load a Customer object in from a file but I don't know how to return the object in the method. As the code stands now I get an error saying return type incompatible java.lang.object found needs Customer.

```
public static Customer loadCustomer(String customerNum) {
    try {
        String fileName = customerNum + ".txt";
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
        Object x = input.readObject();
        return x;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I was thinking I could do something like this but it doesn't work either.

```
public static Customer loadCustomer(String customerNum) {
    try {
        String fileName = customerNum + ".txt";
        InputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);
        Object x = input.readObject();
        Customer y = new Customer(x);
        return y;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

//or do something like this:Customer x = new Customer(input.readObject)
```

Im still in the java learning process so if you see any other errors please let me know. As always I appreciate everyones time for helping me out with this, looking forward to the day when I have the knowledge to pay it forward and help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `Object x = input.readObject();` with `Customer x = (Customer) input.readObject();`

Comment: That seemed to clear that error. Thank you. but now its complaining that the method doesn't have a return statement and places the curser before the last bracket below the catch brackets

Comment: Add `return null;` in the `catch` block, because if it catches an error, there would be no return value! :)

Comment: you rock bro that did it, now i just need to get it to read files properly